# Using SCSS and CSS

Tags: css, command-line, npm, sass, styles

i have a style in `style.css`

```
#someid{
   color:red;
}
```

I have to move this style to SCSS file

Basiclly i have a SCSS file `_form.scss` which looks like this

```
.someclass{
    &-title {
        margin: 0.5em 0em;
        padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $color-border-3;
    }

    .fc {
        margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
        width: 100%;

        label {
            display: block;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }
    }
}
#someid{
    color:red;
}
```

So this does not work.

1. How to run new changes in scss files, so that it should reflect to my application
2. I used `npm install -g scss-compile` to compile SCSS and ran `npm run scss-compile`. this also does not seem to work.
3. Now how to migrate my style.css to scss file

Comment: Use the node-sass package directly. The npm package you are using for compiling is no longer being maintained. Read the command line interface section for set up info.

https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Answer (score 0):

> How to run new changes in scss files, so that it should reflect to my
>   application. 
>   I used npm install -g scss-compile to compile SCSS and ran
>   npm run scss-compile. this also does not seem to work.

According to the docs of scss-compile, after installation of scss-compile you should also add "scss-compile" script to your package.json:

```
 ...
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {   
  "scss-compile": "node-sass _form.scss > result.css",
 },
...
```

For now 'npm run scss-compile' will result in producing result.css from your _form.scss.

> Now how to migrate my style.css to scss file

Your _form.scss is valid (except undefined variable $color-border-3). The rule is simple: "any valid css is valid scss", so all you need is just to copy-paste your working css code to scss file